# How to Create an FTP server via IIS with a public_html page inside it?

Tags: ftp

I am a total novice , no idea on how to proceed . the question I am asking maybe the most basic . but trust me  when I say I am a total novice

I simply want to create an FTP server via IIS and host it onto the internet . Inside the same ftp server , I would like to have a public_html for the entire world to view .

I searched a lot , but got nothing specific to this and i am frustrated . Please do help me with a push in the right direction .A link with step by step instructions would also be very vry help full .

Comment: You want an FTP server to host a web page?

Comment: yes , I would like to have an FTP server host a webpage.

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: Well you can host any type of file you want on an FTP server but it's not going to serve the file as a web page.

Answer (score 0):

FTP is not the same as HTTP, you can't browse a web page via FTP like you would normally do with a web browser. (some browser can connect to FTP using ftp://domain.com in the url) but this is not the same as a regulart http://some_server.com URL)

You can post a web page with instructions on how to connect your FTP site and distribute that URL to the rest of the world.
The instructions will need to tell the user your FTP host, port, username and password on how to connect and access your FTP site.

There are some commercial products that can combine FTP and WEB on a single web page.
Take a look at a FTP Java applet that can be posted on a web page and that applet will connect to your FTP server. Take a look at UnlimitedFTP by Unlimi-Tech Software
http://www.utechsoft.com/products/unlimitedftp/